# Php-cli less resoult

Tags: php

I start coding php-cli script for manipulation with hosts and VirtualHost files in linux.

https://github.com/ErgallM/deep all program

In https://github.com/ErgallM/deep/blob/master/library/Host.php#L34 printing hosts element.

How to less php output?

Comment: Sorry, what? Can you please clarify your question?

Comment: I assume he means Unix's `less`. Not sure what the question is about though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick hack would be to prefix your code with....

```
 <?php

   $reentry='reenteredxx123';
   if ($argv[1]!=$reentry) {
      $script=aray_shift($argv);
      $clean=array_map('escapeshellarg',$argv);
      $cmd="php $script $reentry" . implode(' ',$clean) . ' | less';
      system($cmd);
      exit;
   } else {
      unset($argv[1]);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do fgets() on STDIN file after you output like 30 lines. This will cause user to wait.